# Crystal Reports in VS 2010 - bar chart missing group titles

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart for a set of data which has an increasing number of rows. Whatever I do with the formatting of the chart (auto scaling, no auto scaling, any font size I can find to set anywhere), some of the all-important group titles from the x-axis are not displayed at all, rendering the chart pretty useless. 
Is there anything I can do to either 
a) Force the chart to split over several pages (it's displayed so that the 'x' axis is vertical - hope that makes sense) so it can scale the data titles in a sensible way, or 
b) Get it to print the data titles in smaller font sizes (it seems to ignore whatever I set manually in the chart expert, whether I have auto-scaling on or not) so that more can fit beside the chart and actually line up with the bars
I've been fighting with this report for quite a while now and can't seem to google up anything that mentions this problem with crystal, only with access or sql reports. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you upload a pic of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the x-axis labels being skipped and only displaying every second one there is a setting for that.

Right click on the axis area of the chart and go to Group (X) Axis Settings.

Uncheck 'Skip Group Labels'.

That should fix it and display every grouping. You may need to adjust them to a rotation of 90deg and a smaller font to have them display in a readable manner.